# Qt Qpixmap generates a blurry image

Tags: qt, qpixmap

As part of a larger project i'm trying to draw basic shapes on a QPixmap but the generated image always appears blurry ie. the circle is not a pure red circle, the edges are blurred and the colour is not true red as expected. This becomes an issue later on with what I need the image for. Here's the relevant code snippet, i've played around with antialiasing options and render hints but i've not had any luck. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
QPixmap pixmap(QSize(300,300));
QPainter painter( &pixmap);

painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);

painter.fillRect( QRectF(0, 0, 300, 300),Qt::white);

painter.setPen(Qt::red);
painter.drawEllipse( QPoint(150,150), 75, 75);

painter.setPen(Qt::green);
QLineF line(30, 30, 30, 270);
painter.drawLine(line);

pixmap.save("test1.jpg", "jpg", 100);
```

I've been asked to include an image to show the issue, here's a close up of the image which shows the green line not being true green and the red circle not being true red and with blurred edges.

[image]

Comment: If you have antialiasing enabled then I would expect the edges within the pixmap to appear slightly blurred on close inspection.  Can you edit your post to include an image that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Done! So should i take out the antialiasing line? Even before this line was added I was still having the issue though.

Comment: If you're seeing the blurring even *without* the antialiasing `QPainter` hint then I suspect there's something else going on.  The code as posted but with the `painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);` line removed does exactly what I'd expect; i.e no blurring

Comment: Is it a requirement to be in JPG format?

Comment: No it doesn't have to be a JPG, an answer below suggested using PNG instead which does help but doesn't get rid of the blurring completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you have with the red color is that Qt by default uses chroma color subsampling (2x2 blocks) when saving to JPG format.
The only way to avoid this problem is using another format. Saving the same image with *PNG* format returns  a pure red circle (255,0,0).

Regarding to the blurry circle, it occurs because of `QPainter::Antialiasing` *RenderHint*. In your case, not using any *renderHints* shows a sharp image. Below you can see your image with pure red color (PNG format) and sharp edges (not *RenderHints*). Take into account that the blurriest approach will be using `QPainter::Antialiasing` so avoid it if you are aiming to image sharpeness. Depending on your needs you could try `QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing` [*RenderHint*](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#RenderHint-enum), but nothing else.

[image]

Comment: You should include the image as part of the post rather than a link. It'll be better for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've removed the Antialiasing and changed the format to PNG which does improve the blurring, but it is still slightly blurry, not as clear as your attached image. Could you perhaps show the code you used to generate this image so I can compare it to mine? After playing around, for some reason setting the pen width to 10 seems to get rid of the blurring altogether.

Comment: Ignore that, it does the job perfectly! I'd made a mistake as per usual. Many thanks for the help.